# How to set response headers in serverless.yml?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, http-headers, httpresponse, serverless-framework

I have serverless API which is working with serverless framework version 1.25

Due to security reason I want to add response header. Please help me how can I set below headers via serverless.yml file. Is it necessary to add this header for the security reason?

• Content-Security-Policy: Include default-src 'self'

• Strict-Transport-Security max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload

• X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff

• X-XSS-Protection: 1

• Cache-Control: max- age=0; Expires=-1 or Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT; no-cache, must-revalidate

Below is my serverless application serverless.yaml

```
service: myService
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs6.10
  stage: dev
  region: eu-west-1
  environment:
    REGION: ${self:provider.region}
    PROJECT_NAME: ${self:custom.projectName}
    SERVERLESS_STAGE: ${self:provider.stage}
    SERVERLESS_SERVICE: ${self:service}
    IP_ADDRESS: http://example.com
functions:
   getMyFunction:
     handler: handler.getMyFunction
     timeout: 30
     events:
      - http:
          method: get
          path: api/getMyFunction/v1
          integration: lambda
          cors: true
          authorizer:
            name: authorizerFunc
            identitySource: method.request.header.Token
            authorizationType: AWS_IAM
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Lambda Proxy Integration](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway/). based on the documentation, you need to create a function which will run when someone accesses your API endpoint.

As an example :

```
module.exports.hello = function (event, context, callback) {
    console.log(event); // Contains incoming request data (e.g., query params, headers and more)

    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        headers: {
            "x-custom-header": "My Header Value"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ "message": "Hello World!" })
    };

    callback(null, response);
};
```

And in your serverless.yml

```
functions:
 index:
   handler: handler.hello
   events:
     - http: GET hello
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you use Lambda Integration, you have to put it in your `serverless.yml`.

```
service: myService
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs6.10
  stage: dev
  region: eu-west-1
  environment:
    REGION: ${self:provider.region}
    PROJECT_NAME: ${self:custom.projectName}
    SERVERLESS_STAGE: ${self:provider.stage}
    SERVERLESS_SERVICE: ${self:service}
    IP_ADDRESS: http://example.com
functions:
   getMyFunction:
     handler: handler.getMyFunction
     timeout: 30
     events:
      - http:
          method: get
          path: api/getMyFunction/v1
          integration: lambda
          cors: true
          authorizer:
            name: authorizerFunc
            identitySource: method.request.header.Token
            authorizationType: AWS_IAM
          response:
            headers:
              Content-Security-Policy: "'Include default-src 'self''"
              Strict-Transport-Security: "'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload'"
              X-Content-Type-Options: "'nosniff'"
              X-XSS-Protection: "'1'"
              Cache-Control: "'max-age=0; Expires=-1 or Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT; no-cache, must-revalidate'"
```

Reference: https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway#custom-response-headers

Comment: The code you have pushed is correct but need to add "' '" for the value. I am posting this answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
service: myService 
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs6.10
  stage: dev
  region: eu-west-1
  environment:
    REGION: ${self:provider.region}
    PROJECT_NAME: ${self:custom.projectName}
    SERVERLESS_STAGE: ${self:provider.stage}
    SERVERLESS_SERVICE: ${self:service}
    IP_ADDRESS: http://example.com
functions:
  getMyFunction:
   handler: handler.getMyFunction
   timeout: 30
   events:
    - http:
      method: get
      path: api/getMyFunction/v1
      integration: lambda
      cors: true
      authorizer:
        name: authorizerFunc
        identitySource: method.request.header.Token
        authorizationType: AWS_IAM
      response:
        headers:
          Content-Security-Policy: "'Include default-src 'self''"
          Strict-Transport-Security: "'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload'"
          X-Content-Type-Options: "'nosniff'"
          X-XSS-Protection: "'1'"
          Cache-Control: "'max-age=0; Expires=-1 or Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT; no-cache, must-revalidate'"
```

Comment: Newest version of serverless doesn't like that, Serverless:   at 'functions.login.events[1].httpApi': unrecognized property 'cors'
Serverless:   at 'functions.login.events[1].httpApi': unrecognized property 'response'